# Wordpress: post name vs. page permalink conflict

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, divi-theme

I am using the wordpress divi theme and i have created a page as a landing page for the custom posts. The default for the custom posts is /projects/ and i have changed this to /lifestyle/ using this code

```
<?php
function custom_post_name () {
return array(
'feeds' => true,
'slug' => 'lifestyle', 
'with_front' => false,
 );
  }
  add_filter( 'et_project_posttype_rewrite_args', 'custom_post_name' );
  ?>
```

This works fine

The problem i have now is that my page is clashing with the post category mysite/lifestyle now goes to the post version and not the page. As they both share the same url.

So my question is how can i make the page template version of this url take priority over the post template?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Change the slug of the other page and be done with it?

Comment: Do you know how I can't change the slug of the archive page?

Comment: Go to **Posts > Categories**, hover over your *Lifestyle* category then click on **Edit**. Change the slug and save changes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it isn't possible in WordPress to set a priority with the same URL. You'd either need to change the page name or prefix all your CPTs.

I'd recommend maybe changing your page name to /lifestyles?